# compare the expected values $E[X(Y-1)]$ and $E[X]E[Y-1]$ while $0 < Y < 1$

Tags: expected-value, covariance

X and Y are two positive variables with unknown distributions. It's known that 0 < 1 < Y, and Cov(X,Y) > 0.

Cov(X,Y) is an observation based on real data.

Question - given which circumstance can we find that

E[X(Y-1)] > E[X]E[Y-1] so that Cov(X,Y) > 0?

Comment: There is no way to show this, the variables X,Y need to be positively correlated so we have to know something about their distributions.

Comment: The condition of normal distribution added.

Comment: @yearntolearn If they are normal, they are not (almost surely) positive.

Comment: Then what distribution would make them positive?

Comment: How are you simulating these random variables and getting a positive result? If we can model the simulation adequately, then we may end up with a mathematical proof.

Comment: Sorry @DinosaurEgg I was too fast to answer without thinking twice. I only modeled X as a random variable. I am interested in any distribution that would result in a positive Cov(X,Y).

Comment: @yearntolearn Any distribution that would result in positive $Cov(X,Y)$? Choose $X=Y$  with $X$ having positive variance.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yes that sounds right, as Var(X) > 0 so must be. In this case, X and Y are two different variables.

Comment: @yearntolearn I suggest rewriting your question.  It is very unclear as of now.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you. Question rewritten. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @yearntolearn Still unclear. Is $Cov(X,Y)$ an assumption or a conclusion?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I would say it's a conclusion because it's an observation based on real data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144637/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-yearntolearn).